# Why is my app shown as beta even if totally released?

Tags: android, google-play, release, google-play-console, google-console-developer

••••• Solved •••••
The app is available. It just took some time to appear. The reason why I saw it as beta is because my Google account was used for alpha tests.
If you have the same problem, just delete your account from the testers and wait some hours.

•••••••••••••••••••••

My team and I are working on a mobile game. We tested it in alpha mode and decided to launch it today. From the alpha version, we asked Google to release the app in production mode. The console tells us the app is totally sent but we can't find it on our mobile stores and when I want to see the app on the web store, it shows me the app is in Beta release.

Can someone tell me why we get this ? We didn't ask to pass in beta mode.
Do we just need to wait a bit ?
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Did you change the app's name when updating? Also, please don't post off-topic questions. This has nothing to do with programming.

Comment: No and I thought this could concern any programmer

Comment: When you click on "Voir sur Google Play", can you open that link in an incognito browser window? If you can see the page, then it is effectively available on the store.

Comment: @Pierre, yes I can but the app doesn't appear on the stores for a classic Goole account

Comment: Did you publish it to the correct countries? What's your app's package name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see your app on the Play Store. I searched for it and it shows up as https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=be.barracudapps.tradeontube. So it is published and others can find it. But do you know that your app targets Android 5.0 and up?

Comment: Yeah I can see it too with a "classic Google account".